# Sequence Converges, find how large n must be $|a_n - L| < .01$

Tags: real-analysis

i. Find the number to which the sequence $\{a_n\} = \{3-1/4n\}$converges

ii. If L is the number to which the sequence converges, find how large n must be so that $|a_n - L| < .01$

iii.For $\epsilon >0$ find $n(\epsilon) \backepsilon |a_n - L| < \epsilon$ if $n>n(\epsilon)$

The only confusion for me with this problem is the less than .01. Not sure how to incorporate into my solution, It needs to be with .01 from the limit?

my solution:
i. 3

ii. $|a_n - 3|< \epsilon$ iff $|3 - 1/4n - 3| < \epsilon$ iff $ n > 1/4\epsilon$

iii. for any $\epsilon$, choose $n(\epsilon) = 1/4 \epsilon \backepsilon \forall n > n(\epsilon)$, we have  $|a_n - 3| = |3-1/4n-3| = |1/4n| < 1/4n(\epsilon) = \epsilon$

Comment: iii is just iii in the special case $\epsilon = 0.01$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|a_n - 3| =|\frac{1}{4n}| \leq \frac{1}{4n}<\frac{1}{100}$ so $4n>100\Rightarrow n>\frac{100}{4}=25$